# Libraries for eclipse with CCSv5 from Texas Instruments

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, eclipse, libraries

My system is Ubuntu 11.10 64bit and i have to run a 32bit version of eclipse to use the TI plugins for CCSv5 but it doesn't work.

I tried to run eclipse in a 62bit java environment but it doesn't even start.

Now I got "java version "1.6.0_30"" from Sun in 32bit and now eclipse starts but can't use the TI plug ins and I get the following errors in bash:

```
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64

/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: falsche ELF-Klasse: ELFCLASS64
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
```

and this in a popup-window when Itry to use the plugin:

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.ti.ccstudio.project.ui was unable to load class com.ti.ccstudio.project.ui.internal.wizards.importexport.temp.ExternalProjectImportWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.ti.ccstudio.project.ui (352).
```

T tested the libraries with file:

```
/usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

The ia32-libs are installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 12.04 LTS x64.
Here's what worked for me:
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
Installed Eclipse from repository
Installed the latest Target Management Terminal available from [this](http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/updates/3.0) eclipse plugin repo.
Enabled the `http://rxtx.qbang.org/eclipse/` eclipse plugin repo.
Installed the latest RXTX plugin

It resulted in this:
[image]